# Length of a product of conjugates of an element in a free group

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $F$ be a free group generated by a set $S$. For $g\in 
F$, let $l(g)$ be the length of $g$ with respect to $S$.

Now for $a\in G$ and $g_1,\dotsc,g_n\in G$, let $T=g_1^{-1}ag_1g_2^{-1}ag_2\dotsm g_n^{-1}ag_n$. What can we say about $l(T)$ in terms of $l(a)$?
Assuming that $a$ is cyclically reduced, is it known that $l(T)\geq l(a)$? (I conjectured this, but can't prove it.)

Back ground: The length $l(a^n)$ in terms of $l(a)$ is easily determined. Products of conjugates of $a$ is a natural generalization of powers of $a$. Thus it's natural to ask the relation of the lengths with respect to this generalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Presuming that $G=F$:* For a counterexample when $n=1$, take
$$S = \{s,t\}, \quad a = s^{100} t s^{-100}, \quad g_1 = s^{100}
$$
so
$$l(a) = 201 \quad\text{and}\quad l(g_1^{-1} a g_1) = 1
$$

Comment: Hey, you answer is right. But I just forgot to mention that $a$ is cyclically reduced. (I fixed that in Mathoverflow, but forgot to do it here. I got this fixed now.)

Comment: So, here are two things you can do to avoid wasting the time of your readers and your (potential and actual) answerers. First, if you cross-post, make sure to reference each post in the other one. Second, if you get an answer to the question you asked, don't change the question in a way that invalidates the answer; instead, accept an answer to the question you asked and then, if you want to, post a new question

Comment: Thank you for your interest and suggestion, although I don't know how to reference a post. I admit that I made a mistake, so I corrected it. I don't think it's necessary to post a new question.

Comment: To reference a post you simply use the URL in your browser after clicking on the title of the post.

Comment: You can also get URL's from clicking on the "share" button below each post (and each question).

Comment: Will try, thanks again.